# Angular 5 unit testing http response

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, angular5

I'm trying to unit test my http.get/post/etc responses.

I found this tutorial that was extremely helpful: https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-testing-snippets-httpclient-d1dc2f035eb8

Going through and following that, I've configured my unit tests and I'm able to get everything working, but there's one part that I have that is inconsistent with the tutorial...

In the tutorial, it shows to test the service login function like this:

```
 it(`should emit 'true' for 200 Ok`, async(inject([HttpClientFeatureService, HttpTestingController],
    (service: HttpClientFeatureService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
      service.login('foo', 'bar').subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toBeTruthy();
      });

      backend.expectOne('auth/login').flush(null, { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
  })));
```

And here's the actual method on the service that is being tested:

```
login(user: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set(`user`, user)
      .set(`password`, password);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

    return this.http.post(`auth/login`, body.toString(), { headers, observe: 'response' })
      .map((res: HttpResponse<Object>) => res.ok)
      .catch((err: any) => Observable.of(false));
  }
```

Here's my login function:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    this.loggingService.log('LoginService | login | username: ' + username + '; password: xxxxx');

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { username: username, password: password })
        .map((response: any) => {
            console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));

            if (response && response.length > 0) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return this.parseErrorResponse(response);
            }
        });
}
```

And here's my unit test:

```
it('login should return a valid JWT', async(inject([LoginService, HttpTestingController], (service: LoginService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
    service.login('user', 'password').subscribe((next) => {
        expect(next).toEqual('asdfasdfasdf');
    });

    backend.expectOne(environment.authenticationServiceBaseUrl + 'api/login')
        .flush('asdfasdfasdf', { status: 200, statusText: 'Ok' });
})));
```

You'll notice the difference here is in the map response section. My version is getting back just a string from the unit test's http.post call, while the example shows that it's returning an HttpResponse object and is just checking that the `statusText` property is equal to 'Ok'.

Why is my version returning just the string, while the examples version is returning the actual HttpResponse (which includes status and statusText)? I WANT the tutorial version here...

The example shows that it returns `null` in the body of the response via the flush function call, while I had to add my dummy JWT value in there in order to get my test to pass. Even when I specify that as `null` to be like the test, then the response that I get in the unit test is `null`.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The tutorial uses `observe: 'response'`, which means that events emitted by the returned observable are responses, and not just the body. This is covered in the http tutorial. But I don't understand the way you're creating your test: you should crite the code, and the test, based on what your backend is actually supposed to return. So if the backend is supposed to return a JWT token as a string in the body in case of success, and an error response in case of failure, then testing the status code in your test is useless: your code doesn't use the status code to decide what to do.

Comment: Gotcha, my api service isn't developed yet, so in a way I'm determining what the response should be...

Comment: A typical authentication service would return a 200 or 201 response, containing a JSON body (don't just send strings back), containing the token (but maybe also other information about the logged in user), in case of success. And a 401 response in case of failure

Comment: @JBNizet can you add the observe part as an answer, because that fixed everything for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial uses `observe: 'response'`, which means that events emitted by the returned observable are responses, and not just the body.

This is covered in [the http guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response).

Comment: To elaborate, the HttpClient methods (get, post, etc) have maaany different overloads that return different types of observables depending on the exact signature used. (`Observable<HttpResponse>`, `Observable<HttpEvent>`, etc.) Since the `Observable<any>` that OP's login function returns is not fully typed, it's not obvious what the type of the `response` actually is. I find it helpful to mouse-over code in VSCode to see the real function signature being used, which lets me fill in the appropriate types, rather than `any`. This will also help to mock a proper response with the desired type.